# How to make whole box link clickable?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to make the whole bow link clickable.  As in if I click outside of the word but still in box it will select the link.  I'm sorry if question is confusing.  I have been stuck on it for quite some time.  How do you make the whole box clickable?

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff3b2;

}
.logo{
    font-weight:italic;
    width:4%;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:tahoma;
}
.navbar{
    width:75%;
    height:30px;
    margin:auto;

}
.navbar ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;

}
.navbar li{
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:italic;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 7px;

}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;

}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo">Hello</div>

            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the padding/size styles onto the `li a` rather than just on the `li`

Answer (score 4):

First of all use `display:block` in `<a>` which converts inline tag to block tag nature.

And don't set height and width for `<a>` then use padding in `<a>` instead of `<li>`

```css
body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff3b2;

}
.logo{
    font-weight:italic;
    width:4%;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:tahoma;
}
.navbar{
    width:75%;
    height:30px;
    margin:auto;

}
.navbar ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;

}
.navbar li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:italic;
    border-left: 1px solid black;

}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    //height:20px;
    //width:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    display:block;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo">Hello</div>

            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
.navbar li{
    float:left;
    padding-right:20px; <= DELETE
    padding-left:20px;  <= DELETE
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:italic;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 7px;

}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    height:20px; <= DELETE
    width:20px;  <= DELETE
}
```

to:

```
.navbar li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:italic;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 7px;

}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 40px;  <= ADD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added changes in comment lines, so you can try this:

```
.navbar li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 20px;
            /*padding-left: 20px;*/ //Remove padding
            text-align:center; //Add text-align
            display: block;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: tahoma;
            font-weight: italic;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            width: 90px; //Give specific width
            height: 60px; //Give specific height
        }

    li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        width: inherit; //Take parents width
        height: 100%;
        display: block; //display block
        padding-top: 10px; //add padding to vertical align
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this css

```
 a {
      display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%;   /*  fill the parent  */
    }
```

and there is another way it's work perfectly but it's not valid to use by w3c Standards :

```
<a href='www'><li></li></a>
```

Comment: yes i know and im tell him that is invalid and the right way by css